# Searching for a character or string of characters in a list (like the find function on websites)

Tags: python, list, search, char, find

My first post here.
I'd like to create a search function, searching a list for any raw_input entered.
So far, I've been able to call a path on computer and append each item to a list.
I know I can list.index() for a complete file name, but I'd like it to search for
simply any character(s) one might want to input.

Here's what I've got so far:::

```
import os

list1 = []

x = "/Users/User/temp"

vec = os.listdir(x)

for p in vec:
    list1.append(p)

for line in list1:
    print line

o = raw_input("search>>> ")

print list.index(o)
```

Now, with this code, the filename has to be typed in exactly...
So, it'll take my path(users/user/temp) and make a list from it, search
the list for the filename and return the index at which it lies.

How can I search for say.. (you) in the list and bring up a result that
might be (youarewonderful.txt).

Thanks, I'm very new to Python, so any insight or code improvements are welcome
as well.

-peer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a lead!

Next, I added:::

```
for p in vec:
    if 'yo' in p:
        print p
        print list1.index(p)
```

Sorry Patrick, this is more along the lines of what I wanted to do.  Thanks anyways!  -although I don't quite get what you were getting at.  I'd like to know, though.

Here is completed program, don't know how I got here:::

```
import os
list1 = []
x = "/Users/User/temp"
vec = os.listdir(x)

for p in vec:
    list1.append(p)

for line in list1:
    print line

b = raw_input('search for item in list/path>>> ')

for p in vec:
    if str(b) in p:
        print p
        print list1.index(p)
```

Woo Hoo
-peer

Answer (score 1):

This gives a list of indices:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(vec) if "you" in x]
```

This is called a list comprehension, and it uses the `enumerate` function to keep track of the indices.  If you aren't familiar with these, I recommend the official python tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! BUT  - Still working on this... not getting very far.  I feel like enumerate just provides the index with the entry.  How does this help me search?  Because of the 'if "you" in x' ? And then, how do I make it's index print?

Comment: `enumerate` returns tuples of `(index, item)` So the item in the list is `x` and its index is `i`.  Then you can check the contents of `x` and only keep the index `ii

Comment: check out my answer, Patrick... any improvements would be welcome.  -thanks